# How to get all attachments for a wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently attempting to get all the attachments that are attached to each individual post on WordPress and allow a user to download the attachments.

I have looked into the `get_attached_media()` function in WordPress but I am not sure how to make the files downloadable once I get the media.

Comment: eg `foreach($posts as $post) { $images = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID); foreach($images as $image) { echo '<a href="" download></a>' ...`

Comment: I have this:

<?php 
                            $attachments = get_attached_media('', $post->ID);
                            <ul>
                            foreach($attachments as $attachment) { ?>
                            <li src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID); ?>" ></li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>

Comment: But it is not working... Any pointers?

Comment: Do you need all image attachment in post single page?

Answer (score 12):

Try this code this may help you:

With below code you can fetch all type of media attachment if you need particular media type then you can add one more args  'post_mime_type' => 'image'

```
<?php if ( $post->post_type == 'post' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
        $attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
        ) );

                if ( $attachments ) {
                    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                        $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
                        $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
                        echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
                    }

                }
            }
        ?>
```

Another way you can achieve this:

```
$media = get_attached_media('image', get_the_ID()); // Get image attachment(s) to the current Post
print_r($media);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `post_parent` field DOES NOT retrieve attachments of the post in all cases.  This value is filled on the database ONLY if the image is loaded and attached at the same time (on the post/page editor) But it's value will be 0 zero if image has been previously added to the library.

> `post_parent` just means the image was initially uploaded for this
> particular post (as opposed to uploading via Media Library screen),

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30691